# Bash: Nginx Version check cut

Tags: bash, nginx, cut

I'm trying to check if the installed nginx version is equal with the version defined in a config file.

My code:

```
#check version

command="nginx -v"
nginxv=$( ${command} 2>&1 )
nginxvcutted="echo ${nginxv:21}"
nginxonpc=$( ${nginxvcutted} 2>&1 )

if [ $nginxonpc != ${NGINX_VERSION} ]; then
  echo "${error} The installed Nginx Version $nginxonpc is DIFFERENT with the Nginx Version ${NGINX_VERSION} defined in the config!"
else
    echo "${ok} The Nginx Version $nginxonpc is equal with the Nginx Version ${NGINX_VERSION} defined in the config!"
fi
```

This code 'can' work, but I have got a problem:
If the version number changes, the cut number (`nginxv:21` in this example) doesn't fit anymore.

Example:

```
nginx-1.13.12 vs nginx-1.15.0 (13 vs 14 chars)
```

Is there any way to get this working, without that trouble?

**Solution:**
I adapted the solution from @Mohammad Saleh Dehghanpour and it's working like a charm:

```
command="nginx -v"
nginxv=$( ${command} 2>&1 )
nginxlocal=$(echo $nginxv | grep -o '[0-9.]*$')

echo $nginxlocal
1.15.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expression instead of cut. For example to extract version number from `nginx-1.15.0` use:

`echo 'nginx-1.15.0' | grep -o '[0-9.]*$'`

Output: `1.15.0`

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working for me!
I adapted it (storing the result into a variable).
But if I'm trying to replace command="nginx -v" with command="uname -r" it doesn't work (the result is 64). But uname -r is showing 4.9.0-6-amd64 (the whole kernel release number). But I only need 4.9.0-6 (and 4.9.0-xxx for example). I already tried to manipulate the grep settings to [0-9.][0-9.][0-9.], but I'm not able to understand how it works actually.

Comment: If someone has a long version string, then this approach will help you: `echo "nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)" | awk -F' ' '{print $3}' | grep -o '[0-9.]*$'`

Answer (score 1):

Combining everything on this page I got:

`nginx -v 2>&1 | awk -F' ' '{print $3}' | cut -d / -f 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash variable and then extract the versing using grep.

```bash
version=$(nginx -v 2>&1); echo $version | grep -o '[0-9.]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the answers here are so complicated. There's no reason to involve `awk` or `grep`, which have more portability issues and marginally worse performance than plain old `cut`.

The actual problem is that `nginx -v` prints to STDERR instead of STDOUT, hence why the solutions that involve redirecting the error stream to the output stream (i.e. `2>&1`) work.

The simplest solution:

`nginx -v 2>&1 | cut -d'/' -f2`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the above comments don't account for nginx plus.

Something like:

```
nginx -v  2>&1 | grep -oP 'nginx/\K[0-9.]+'
```

Is better ( and something I use ).

On systems like alpine, that don't come with a version of `grep` that facilitates the above arguments. I use something like:

```
nginx -v 2>&1 | sed 's/.*nginx\///' |  cut -d ' ' -f1
```

```
➜ version=$(nginx -v 2>&1 | sed 's/.*nginx\///' |  cut -d ' ' -f1)
➜ echo $version                                                   
1.25.1
```